# When I add a particular field, the preview disappears. Why?

Tags: views, 9

I have a Drupal 9 view which shows the fields of a particular content type. This content type has a particular field, *ver*. When I add this field in the view, the preview disappears and I get this error in the error log.

> Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::theme() in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->elementPreRenderRow() (line 779 of /var/www/html/onemodernizeprodwcm/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php)

I haven't done anything in the themes of my site; I am just trying to add this view.
Please help.

Comment: What type of field is it?  What module is providing the field?

Comment: The field is a plain text field. The content type has this field. I am trying to place it in a view.

Comment: Are you using one of the standard core themes?  Which theme are you using specifically?

Comment: I am using the default bartik theme